# How to programmatically (C#) create and add a default (HTML) signature in Outlook 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, registry

Sorry for bothering you - but maybe somebody can help me here!?

We are creating an Outlook 2013 VSTO Add-In to manage Corporate Signatures centrally and publish them to every user as a default signature.

We already managed to create the appropriate HTML files and store them in the correct folder.

All the same, there is no problem at all to modify the appropriate Registry keys, e. g.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\General
```

where we set the value of the "Signatures" element to the folder name of the signature file(s)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\MailSettings
```

where we set the value of the "NewSignature" and "ReplySignature" elements to the name of the default signature file

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676
```

where - within the appropriate user profile folder - we need to set the values of the "New Signature" and "Reply-Forward Signature" elements to the binary-converted name of the default signature file.

**All these operations work perfectly fine and afterwards, we find the correct files in the appropriate folders and the correct entries in the Registry keys.**

However, when creating **the very first eMail** after the Outlook and eMail Signature Add-In setup, **users do NOT see the default signature**!

**Only as soon as they once open the "Signatures" dialog in the mail editor screen - and it is really enough to only open it; no need to click "OK" or so! - then they get the signature!**

So my question is: is there any other Registry key or whatever that need(s) to be set so that the signature appears right away - without having to make users open the "Signatures" dialog!? Does anybody know what happens in the background of this dialog!?

What do I overlook!?

Thank you very much everyone - I truly hope you can help me here!

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: All the signatures saved in the outlook is user specific and saved at location [USERDIRECTORY]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures. You can use them explicitly if you want any purpose to be solved forcefully. Though, I am a bit confused, what's your exact requirement ? Can you post an image of your requirement ?

Comment: Hi Rohit - thank you very much. Actually, I am fully aware of the file locations and stuff. All the files are there in the respective folders - as are the registry entries listed above. However, the signature only appears after I once invoke the standard signature dialog... That is my problem...

Comment: If you are enable to access the signature after invoking the standard dialog, its probably because, the object you are trying to access needs a handle or the object is maintained in some other appdomain. 
Nevertheless, as Dmitry said, to extending your email experience you rather should use Extended MAPI that features lots of facilities.

Answer (score 1):

The `"9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676"` part is profile and account specific (it is profile section uid). It will be different for different users, profiles, and different accounts within the same profile .

You can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IOlkAccountManager, double click on the account, New and reply signature names will be in properties 0x0016001F and 0x0017001F respectively.

These properties can be set using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) on [IOlkAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960403(v=office.15).aspx) interface. You can also set them using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author - any language) - [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) object exposes `NewMessageSignature` and `Reply` properties as well as `Fields[]` (can be used to set any property).